There are embeddings of 5 docs in azure search index, I want to chat with the embeddings of only one document
I am using ConversationalRetrievalChain of Langchain.
question_generator = LLMChain(llm=self.llm, prompt=CONDENSE_QUESTION_PROMPT, verbose=False)
        doc_chain = load_qa_with_sources_chain(self.llm, chain_type="stuff", verbose=False, prompt=self.prompt)
        chain = ConversationalRetrievalChain(
            retriever=self.vector_store.as_retriever(),
            question_generator=question_generator,
            combine_docs_chain=doc_chain,
            return_source_documents=True,
            # top_k_docs_for_context= self.k
        )
        result = chain({"question": question, "chat_history": chat_history})
        sources = "\n".join(set(map(lambda x: x.metadata["source"], result['source_documents'])))

I want the answer generated from only one source document which is uploaded in that session not based on all the embeddings for all the documents present in the index. Can you please help me with the same.
I tried out with different solutions but none seems to be working.

According to this documentation  you can provide the filter parameter while using Retriever which filter on document metadata.
So, alter your code like below.
chain = ConversationalRetrievalChain(
            retriever=self.vector_store.as_retriever(search_kwargs={'filter': {'id':'your document id'}}),
            question_generator=question_generator,
            combine_docs_chain=doc_chain,
            return_source_documents=True,
            # top_k_docs_for_context= self.k
        )

You can also retrieve the documents from specific paper by giving filter like below.
self.vector_store.as_retriever(
    search_kwargs={'filter': {'paper_title':'GPT-4 Technical Report'}}
)

